# Syntax Error for Pyspark CombineBy key executable Example

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to some example in Pyspark using Databricks. I am getting syntax error. Not sure, what am I missing here

```
data = sc.parallelize( [(0, 2.), (0, 4.), (1, 0.), (1, 10.), (1, 20.)] )

sumCount = data.combineByKey(lambda value: (value, 1),
                         lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + 1),
                         lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))

averageByKey = sumCount.map(lambda (label, (value_sum, count)): (label, value_sum / count))
```

The error which i am receiving [image]

Comment: The arrow `^` shows you where you have the syntax error. After `lambda` you should put variable names, `(` symbol is not accepted, thus you get the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`map()` will iterate over the elements and not within the elements. To make it work, just use a single variable in the `lambda` which will select elements and then use the indices to calculate.

```
sumCount.collect()
# [(0, (6.0, 2)), (1, (30.0, 3))]

avgByKey = sumCount.map(lambda k: (k[0], k[1][0] / k[1][1]))
avgByKey.collect()
# [(0, 3.0), (1, 10.0)]
```